# Storing currency in SQlite android database

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I am trying to store currency values in sqlite database in android. I don't think so that `int` will be used here. I have heard that `Bigdecimal` can be used. If anyone can tell me the way it should be used to send values to sqlite database.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Store the BigDecimal as a String.

You can use the toPlainString() method.

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal();
String s = b.toPlainString();
```

Then when you pull it from the database you can create a new BigDecimal.

```
BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal(String s)
```

Believe it or not SQLite 3.0 stores all data types as strings even if you say it should be an Integer.  Take a look at [this web page from the official SQLite website](http://www.sqlite.org/version3.html) and scroll down to the "Manifest Typing and BLOB Support" section.  It talks about how it will let you store strings in columns of other types.

Comment: I do not believe you: SQLite 3.0 stores integers as integers. It was the old version 2.8 that stored everything as strings.

Comment: That's just wrong.  Go to the site (I just fixed the link) and search for: The difference is that SQLite 3.0 will still store the data even if a format conversion is not possible.

Comment: You should include the previous sentence from that page as well: "When data is inserted into a column, that column will make an attempt to convert the data format into the column's declared type". When you declare a column as Integer and store the string '12345' into it, SQLite will convert that string to integer and store it as integer.

Comment: I believe this presents an issue when you want to use aggregate functions, as you can't aggregate a STRING column.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Int here. Since SQlite use 8 bytes for int, the max values is 2^64, which is 1.8446744e+19 - 1, more or less 10^18, big enough for the currency.

Also us